# Особый тип склонения "на согласный"

Tags: грамматика

какие из перечисленных слов относились раньше к особому типу склонения "на согласный": депо, окно, дело, благо, просо, тело, слово.

Comment: У вас есть свои предположения? Нечто подобное тому, что вы описываете, было в старославянском... или вас интересует именно русский язык?

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, поэтому могу только комментировать. Это слово - ***слово***. В старославянском во множественном числе и косвенных падежах основа приобретала  "наращение"  -es-.  (сравните современное словеса, по образцу небо-небеса). В грамматике старославянского такие слова относились к гркппе склонений "на согласный". см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: Тело — телеса...

Comment: Да, тело, кажется, тоже... Точно не помню.

Comment: @behemothus вопрос переоткрыт.